# Add multiple drop-down after each row inside JavaScript table(for loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get drop-down list on click add more button inside a table which comes from for loop, after each row of installment & date and  I need one more row with drop-down list and one input for amount and also I can increase many with click to add more button. Please help, I am beginner.

Thank you ☺

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "select_feeheads.php",
  success: function(resultData) {
    feeData=resultData;
}
});
$('#submit').hide();
$('#programId').change(function() {
var value =$(this).val();
console.log(value);
if(value===0){
    $('#submit').hide();  
}else{
    $('#submit').show();
}
var table = $("#resultTable");
var resultHtml = '';
var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
    x++; //text box increment
    var select = '<select id="feeheads" class="form-control">';
    for(var i=0;i<feeData.length;i++)
    {
        select +='<option       value="'+feeData[i].id+'">'+feeData[i].title+'</option>';
    }
    select += '</select>';
    for(var i = 0 ; i < value ; i++) {
        resultHtml += ["<tr>",
        '<td id="No_Installment">',
        (i+1),
        '</td>',
        '<td><label>Installment:</label><input type="text"   value="Installment" id="Installment" autocomplete="off" ></td>',
        '<td><label>Due Date:</label><input id="date" type="date"  placeholder=""><br></td>',
        '</tr>',
        "<tr>",
        '<td clolspan="3"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id=""  placeholder="" value="Add Fields"></td>',
        '</tr>',
        '<tr>'
         $(wrapper).append('<div class="fee_hd_amt"><div class="form-  inline"><div class="form-group"><label for="email" class="">Fee Head:</label></div>'+select+'</div><div class="form-inline"><div class="form-group amt_label"><br><label>Amount: </label></div><input type="text" id="amount"/></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');].join("\n");
     }
    resultHtml += ["<tr>",
    "<td>", 
    "</td>",
    '<td><input type="button" value="sunmit" onclick="submit()" </td>',
    "<td>", 
    "</td>",
    '</tr>'].join("\n");
    table.html(resultHtml);
    return false;
   }
   });
   });
   });
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: what error you are getting in console?

Comment: If I am writing the code for drop-down list out side the for loop and table its working fine

Comment: in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: please show full error.and try to solve all error present in console.

Comment: feehead_course.php:190 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier,
Here only one error in console and if its seems coming because I am writing $(wrapper).append(

Comment: Unexpected identifier ?

Comment: Yes, Unexpected identifier. but I don't know what to do.

Comment: 1) feeData you defined is local.define it as global  2)duplicate variable x

Comment: Thank you Mr. Santosh for help, I got the solution. ☺